# Get [Item Name] Command not working, I'm stuck

Tags: python

Below is my current code, I have no problems when I enter the go commands but as soon as I try to input the get item name command I get an invalid response. Can someone please help?

```
# A dictionary for the created text game
# The dictionary links a room to other rooms.

current_room = "Grand Hall"
inventory = []
rooms = {
    "Grand Hall": {"South": "Alderaan", "North": "Hoth", "East": "Naboo", "West": "Mustafar"},
    "Alderaan": {"North": "Grand Hall", "East": "Tatooine"},
    "Tatooine": {"West": "Alderaan"},
    "Mustafar": {"East": "Grand Hall"},
    "Hoth": {"East": "Kashyyyk", "South": "Grand Hall"},
    "Kashyyyk": {"West": "Hoth"},
    "Naboo": {"North": "Dagobah", "West": "Grand Hall"},
    "Dagobah": {"South": "Naboo"}
}

room_items = {
    "Grand Hall": ["Invincibility bracelet"],
    "Alderaan": ["Soul Stone"],
    "Tatooine": ["Death Stone"],
    "Mustafar": ["Chaos Stone"],
    "Hoth": ["Genesis Stone"],
    "Kashyyyk": ["Evolution Stone"],
    "Naboo": ["Nightmare Stone"],
    "Dagobah": ["War Stone"]
}

commands = ["go North", "go South", "go East", "go West", "get [item name]", "exit"]


# Define a function to display the available commands
def show_valid_commands():
    print("Available commands:")
    for cmd in commands:
        print("- " + cmd)


# Define a function to display the player's status
def show_status():
    print("You are currently in the " + current_room)
    print("Inventory: " + str(inventory))
    print("Items in this room: " + str(room_items.get(current_room, [])))


# Start the game loop
while True:
    # Display the current status and available commands
    show_status()
    show_valid_commands()

    # Get input from the player
    command = input("What would you like to do? ")

    # Validate the input
    if command not in commands:
        print("Invalid command. Please enter a valid command.")
        continue

    # Handle the exit command
    if command == "exit":
        break

    # Handle the get [item name] command
    if command.startswith("get "):
        item_name = command[4:].strip()  # remove leading/trailing whitespaces
        if item_name in room_items.get(current_room, []):
            room_items[current_room].remove(item_name)
            inventory.append(item_name)
            print(f"You picked up the {item_name}.")
        else:
            print(f"There is no {item_name} in this room.")
        continue

    # Handle the go [direction] command
    if command.startswith("go "):
        direction = command[3:]
        next_room = rooms[current_room].get(direction)
        if next_room is None:
            print("There's no room in that direction. Please choose another direction.")
        else:
            current_room = next_room
        continue

# Output a message to let the player know the game has ended
print("You have exited the game.")
```

I'm stuck and I can't wrap my brain around what could be wrong..

Comment: `I get an invalid response` share the full error stacktrace here so we don't have to hunt through your code for where the error is potentially happening. Your code should also be a [mre] regardless.

Comment: always be sure to include the complete error, verbatim, as text not a screenshot

Comment: That is the thing whenever I try to get the item from the current room i get an invalid response. Sorry about the code this was my first time posting on here.

Comment: It isn't an error I just get this:

You are currently in the Grand Hall
Inventory: []
Items in this room: ['Invincibility bracelet']
Available commands:
- go North
- go South
- go East
- go West
- get [item name]
- exit
What would you like to do? get Invincibility bracelet
Invalid command. Please enter a valid command.

Answer (score 0):

I tried out your code and did a bit of debugging on your command test.  Basically, this statement works for movement and if one literally entered "get [item name]":

```
if command not in commands:
```

What you would want to do is add an addition test for checking that the command starts with "get " something like this:

```
if command not in commands and command.startswith("get ") == False:
```

When I tested that refactored code, I could pick up inventory.

Give that a try and see if that meets the spirit of your project.

Answer (score 0):

`if command not in commands` 
Is some kind of optimisation you don't really need.
Drop it and just put at the end of your filters :

> `print("Invalid command. Please enter a valid command.").   continue`